# Why do some folks continue to add subsequent duplicate #include some duplicate header files in their projects?

Tags: c++, include, sfml, header-files

Why do some folks continue to add subsequent duplicate `#include` some duplicate header files in their projects?

**Bat.h**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

**Pong.cpp**

```
#include "Bat.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

Wasn't they paying attention?

Comment: *Wasn't they paying attention?* -- What if there are hundreds, if not thousands of source files?  Are you going to try an inventory each one to see which `#include` file should be where?  Second, what if `Bat.h` requires that header to compile, regardless of whether it is included in `Pong.cpp`?

Comment: If pong.cpp needs SFML/Graphics.hpp it should include it directly. Who knows what will happen to Bat.h in the future? The problem with C++ is not that programmers create these multiple inclusions, it's that there is no reliable way to know when these multiple inclusions are desirable.

Comment: You're really asking what is wrong with implicit header dependencies. Because they shroud, not convey, dependencies. The engineer working on Pong.cpp shouldn't have to rely on `Bat.h` for *anything* except what Bat.h itself declares. If I change `Pong.cpp` to no longer include `Bat.h` and am suddenly greeted with a raft of compilation errors because none of my SFML usage works anymore, that's bad. Likewise, if I change Bat.h to no longer require, and therefore include, SFML headers, Pong.cpp shouldn't suffer for it if it still requires SFML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to include the headers that the *current* file depends on. E.g. in Pong.cpp, you're not obliged to know whether Bat.h (which you supposedly also included) depends on `<SFML/Graphics.hpp>` or on another graphics library or no graphics library at all. Since double include is something we can prevent (using include guards, `#pragma once`), it's not a problem to list every dependency, but it's an issue to miss one.

Comment: We cannot **portably** prevent double include with `#pramga once`; it is not standard C++, and there are build environments where it cannot be implemented correctly.

Comment: @PeteBecker Hence I wrote include guards first. However, OP will likely encounter codes that use `#pragma once` as it's quite widespread in many codebases.

Comment: @lorro Do you mean **Bat.h**, right, not **Bat.hpp**?